# How to pass connection string to UnitOfWork project from startup.cs asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I created constructor in `AppDbContext` and context is implement in `UnitofWork` which pass string to context but how can I pass connection string to at *startup.cs* when I register `unitofwork`. `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` are in different project

Following is my code,

connection string to constructor

```
private readonly string _connection;
public AppDbContext(string connection) 
{

    _connection=connection;

}
```

UnitOfWork constructor

```
public UnitOfWork(string connection)
{
    _context =  new AppDbContext(connection);
}
```

in *StartUp.cs*, can I pass the connection string below, reading from *appsettings.json*?

```
 services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Comment: Don't do that. if already using DI then inject the context into the UOW

Comment: so I  read connection from appsettings.json from data project and pass it to context. right ?

Comment: You read the appsetting.json of the root project. copy the connection string over to that json file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that. If already using DI then inject the context into the UOW and configure the context during startup.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    public UnitOfWork(AppDbContext context) {
        _context =  context;
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

And create the database context using the following example.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)  {
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

You then register everything including the context with dependency injection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

configuration reads the connection string from the *appsettings.json* file.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "connection string here"
  }

}
```

Comment: Awesome :) works like butter. I have one more question, is it possible to use JWT for APIs only like api/v1/customers . Meaning JWT will only work if URL is api/v1/whatever. I want to limit access to api by customer name which I have username for each customer token was issued, token has username in it. So what I want is Api/v1/costomers/username/addresses, so authorize attribute will check if jwt token username match the username in url, if not then response message "you dont have access to this api with that username". Thank youuuuuuuuu

Comment: Yes but that is a whole new topic and question. You should try it out first and if you get stuck then ask a new question. There are many answer on SO on that topic so I suggest searching first.

Comment: Ok thanks understood. Stackoverflow should have kinda of tipping system where poeple can offer something like pluralsight has,where people pay something by will to experts.Thank you